# Why is deploying gradle java app to heroku failing?

Tags: java, git, heroku

I am trying to deploy a gradle java app to heroku from my local machine. My project contains the following files

[image]

I have defined the following tasks in my build.gradle

```
task stage {
  dependsOn build
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.12'
}
```

The content of ProcFile is as follows:

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

While executing `git commit heroku master` I get the following error

[image]

while executing `git ls-files gradle` the following files are listed
[image]

Could you please suggest why I am getting the error while deploying the app to heroku server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you are using gradlew, then you must also add your
>   `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar` and
>   `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` to your Git repository. If
>   you do not add these files, you will receive an error such as:
>
> ```
> -----> executing ./gradlew stage
>        Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
> ```

And to solve it:

> You can add the wrapper files by running these commands:
>
> ```
> git add gradle/wrapper
> git commit -m "Gradle Wrapper"
> ```

From [Deploying Gradle apps on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-gradle-apps-on-heroku#overview).

Comment: If you look closely I have already added them otherwise executing git ls-files gradle command wouldnt have listed gradle-wrapper.jar and gradle-wrapper.properties files.

Comment: Try running `git ls-tree -r HEAD:gradle`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this

```
task stage{
    dependsOn build}
    task wrapper(type:Wrapper){
    gradleVersion = '5.6.1'
}
```

Instead try using this:

`task stage(dependsOn: ['clean', 'installDist'])`